# Jquery Accordeon Multi Level Menu not showing submenus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

Im working on a multilevel accordeon menu using Jquery. Everything works fine when toggle the first submenu but when i have one more level of submenus they don't show up / don't do anything. Im pretty sure it's because of something im not doing quit well with the css treatment on the jquery but i just can't figure it out.

Here's the online test:

[Example](http://wearehellyeah.com/test/menu.html#)

You can check the problem clicking on the first option ("Actualitat dia a dia") and then on the last item of the submenu ("Actualidad") that have also a submenu but it doesn't show up or toggle.

Here's the jquery

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    $(".menu-desplegable > ul > li:has(ul)").addClass("has-sub");

    $('.menu-desplegable > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    $('.menu-desplegable li').removeClass('active');            
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }

        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('.menu-desplegable ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        }

        if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
        return false;
    } else {
    return true;    
     }
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the click element to be `.menu-desplegable > ul > li > a` so only the direct child `a` is bound to that listener.

You need to change your click element to `.menu-desplegable > ul li a` so that a nested `ul li a` can be clicked. Then you need to change the block that handles sliding the `ul` up.

**Change:**

```
if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('.menu-desplegable ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
}
```

**To:**

```
if (checkElement.is('ul') && !checkElement.is(':visible')) {
    checkElement.slideDown('normal');
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/p3bFz/).

Comment: ok @Kyle so what i have to do is .menu-desplegable > ul > li a ? im pretty sure that's part of the problem but i have been working around that and still not working

Comment: @Lowtrux Check my edited version, i have included an example of how you could do it.

Comment: Working fine on the togle side now THANKS A LOT @Kyle, now i have noticed that when you click a submenu item (with a nested ul) the class active (the one that insert the arrow down background when a link is clicked) is not working. I have updated my test site.

Comment: @Lowtrux Your css selector `.menu-desplegable >ul >li.has-sub.active >a span:after` should be `.menu-desplegable >ul li.has-sub.active >a span:after` and you will need to add the `<span></span>` inside the `a` tag.

Comment: Working just fine now @Kyle thanks a lot, i owe you big time !

Answer (score 0):

I have the working solution in this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/QQBbe/6/

Basically just change the javascript as follows:

```
$(".menu-desplegable ul li:has(ul)").addClass("has-sub");

// this will prevent the nested menu items from triggering 
// the .has-sub click event as it applies to itself and all of it's children
$('.menu-desplegable').on("click", "li", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// I would delegate the on click event like this, 
// in case you decide to dynamically add more menu options
$('.menu-desplegable').on("click", ".has-sub", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // if the targets nested ul is not visible, display it
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {

        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).children("ul").slideDown('normal');
    } else {

        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).children("ul").slideUp('normal');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark is actually a really nice way to add more submenus to the menu, nice one.